# working on cron-parser for node.js

Tags: node.js

I need help on using cron-parser for node.js
I don't quite understand how the job will run then log the result of the cron job.

Based on the examples given here https://github.com/harrisiirak/cron-parser
it's iterating the time/interval of the expression instead of the normal cron job that will only show result/s of job when the actual cron job finished.

Questions are, how do I create a normal cron job that will only run, let's say every minute and how could I create multiple jobs that will simultaneously and asynchronously run 3 and 5 minutes respectively.

This is what I did which should run every 5 minutes which unfortunately doesn't print any results every 5 minutes.

```
try {
        var interval = parser.parseExpression('*/5 * * * *');

        while (true) {
            try {
                var obj = interval.next();

                if (obj.done)
                    console.log("Cron Job: run every 5 minutes.");
            } 
            catch (e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (err) {
        console.log('cron parser error: ' + err.message);
    }
```

**EDIT**
So technically, I can't cron-parser to create jobs so instead going with cron module to handle my cron jobs. I got the cron job working also creating multiple jobs. Problem now is whenever I create multiple cron jobs using in array, first job successfully runs, but on the second job, right after it hit the time to run it, it fails and gives me

```
uncaughtException: timer._repeat is not a function
```

This is what I did:

```
for (var data in lists){
        sampleData.find({ id: lists[data].id }, function(err, samples){
            if (err){
                console.log("Server error");
            }
            else{
                for (var sample in samples){
                    new cron("*/3 * * * *", function() {
                        console.log(sample);
                    }, null, true, null);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `cron-parser`, as the name suggests, _parses_ cron job files. It's not an implementation of `cron` functionality itself.

Comment: okay thanks.. after parsing cron jobs, can the parse cron job used to other modules like the answer (cron module)?

Comment: I don't see why you would want to take that detour, as the `cron` module can already parse cron files.

Comment: just my curiosity since it can parse cron job files but not implement cron functionality, I just thought that maybe there's more to cron-parser than just parsing cron job files

Answer (score 2):

If you can use 'cron' module, you can do like this

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('*/3 * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every 3 second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');

new CronJob('*/6 * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every 6 second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');

new CronJob('*/7 * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every 7 second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: have you tried creating multiple jobs through loop?